# Creating a custom unbound helper in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, localization, handlebars.js

In an ember.js application, I have created a custom helper which is used for text localization. Specifically, it is passing the value given to the helper through Jed, a gettext-style text translation library like so:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('_', function(value, options) {
    return Lang.gettext(value); 
});
```

And in my templates:

```
{{_ "Translate Me"}}
```

The problem is that ember renders this as a bound helper, i.e. the rendered text value is surrounded in `<script id="metamorph-*">` tags, but as the values will never change, I want them to be unbound in order to avoid the extra overhead and markup.

In the API docs I did see the workaround solution for this:

> The {{unbound}} helper can be used with bound helper invocations to render them in their unbound form, e.g.

However I would much prefer a way to just globally define my helper as an unbound helper, so that I don't have to type `{{unbound _ "Foo"}}` for every localized string. Not to mention that doing this would cause the strings to not be parseable by the library I use ([xgettext-template](https://github.com/gmarty/xgettext)) to extract all the localized strings from the source code.

Comment: are you sending in bound properties?  or are you always sending in raw text?  aka {{_ translateThisProperty}}

Comment: @kingpin2k always raw text

Comment: Thanks for this question. Using `registerHelper` works fine for the base case, but what about `ngettext`? I want to do `{{ngettext 'person' 'people' count}}`, where `count` is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer, if you aren't binding properties to your function you can use `registerHelper`

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('_', function(value, options) {
    return value + 'moo';
});
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks. Its interesting that the `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` method isn't documented, while the `helper` and `registerBoundHelper` methods are. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

just in case you may need this.

Calling a Handlebars Helper From Another Handlebars Helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('_', function(value, options) {
    return Lang.gettext(value);
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function(value, options){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    args.unshift(value);
    args.unshift('_');
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.unbound.apply(this, args);

});
```

use like this `{{i18n "Translate Me"}}`

here is [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lukamodi/22/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: All I ended up needing was the `registerHelper` method as @kingpin2k demonstrated, but that technique for combining helpers is definitely useful.